# Finding Equivalence Classes of Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations, quadratic-forms, change-of-basis

I am struggling to see how to find equivalence classes of Quadratic forms over $ \mathbb{R} $ .

I know the criteria for the equivalence class is under congruence i.e. $x$ congruent to $y$ iff there is a change of basis which takes us from quadratic form $x$ to quadratic form $y$ .

Comment: Read Conway's "sensual quadratic form"